# Using Pandas to read a csv file is there a way to autodetect dd-mm-yyyy vs mm-dd-yyyy formatting?

Tags: python, csv, date, pandas, datetime

The format of date data in a csv file I am reading into a dataframe is dd-mm-yyyy

ie

```
12-02-2017 23:37:45
12-02-2017 23:52:17
13-02-2017 00:02:28
```

Using the following code to read a csv file:

```
data = pd.read_csv(filename, header=header, engine='c', error_bad_lines=False)
```

the dataframe contains dates in format

```
2017-12-02T23:37:45
2017-12-02T23:52:17
2017-02-13T00:02:28
```

ie Pandas appears to assume input is mm-dd-yyyy until a month doesn't fit then flips to a dd-mm-yyyy assumption.

I have also tried:

```
date_parser = pd.datetools.to_datetime
data = pd.read_csv(filename, header=header, parse_dates=True, infer_datetime_format=True, date_parser=date_parser, engine='c', error_bad_lines=False)
```

With the same result.

The problem is that users could be uploading data with either mm-dd-yyyy or dd-mm-yyyy format.

I could read in the text file and run some manual Python string checking, but is there a way to do this automatically with Pandas?

Comment: Are there only two date formats?

Comment: No, could be any of a number of date formats so I need to use something that is able to autodetect a variety of dates. I am thinking if I could read in the date as a string into a dataframe then do some checking on that specific column and assume day before month type input if the data is indeterminate. The other option is to force the user to specify date type if absolutely necessary.

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this is to read the csv file, parse the dates using dateutil with a default dayfirst=True.

Note that I added a radio box to the user input screen to determine if dates were day or month first.

Similar can be achieved by setting dayfirst=True in pd.read_csv(), however I had issues with pandas using the index column as the date column.

Dates read from csv and converted using:

```
def extract_clean_dates_from_csv(self, file_path, contains_header, date_col, day_first):
    with open(file_path, "r") as f:
        reader = csv.reader(f)
        reader_list = list(reader)
    parsed_dates = self.convert_dates(reader_list, contains_header, date_col, day_first)
    return parsed_dates

def convert_dates(self, reader_list, contains_header, date_col, day_first):
    parsed_dates = []
    headline = True
    for row in reader_list:
        if (headline and contains_header):
            headline = False
            continue
        parsed_date = parse(row[date_col], dayfirst=day_first)
        parsed_dates.append(parsed_date)
    return parsed_dates
```

Then I just replaced the dataframe original date column with the new parsed dates:

```
df.iloc[:, date_col] = parsed_dates
```